# air required for flex on android?

Tags: apache-flex, air

Looking at adobe flex for cross-platform mobile apps.

Does the final apps require adobe air on target devices (iOS / android) to run?

regards,
/t

Comment: "require" as in "download separatly from market"

Comment: As my anser explains, it isn't even an option to "download it separately from [the] market" in iOS.  It is possible in Android (and was required in earlier versions), but as of Air 3.0, it is no longer required that the user "download [it] separately from the market".

Comment: thanks. swell. great. have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

In IOS, you were never required to have Air installed and the packager bundles the binaries with your app.  See Adobe's document on [Building ADOBE AIR Applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/air_buildingapps.pdf) where it says:

> On iOS, a separate AIR runtime is not installed; each iOS AIR app is a
>   stand-alone application

Until recently, a separate Air runtime was required to be installed on Android devices.  As of Air 3.0, that requirement is now optional.

Air 3.0 includes a feature called "Captive Runtime" which allows you to package the required Air binaries with your app in Android as well (as well as desktop deployments).  If you choose this packaging option, you do not need to require that Air be installed separately.  It is still an option but it is no longer required.

"Captive Runtime" is available now through the command line and will be available soon through Flash Builder 4.6.

More info [here](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2011/10/11/captive-runtime-packaging-in-air-3-0/) and [here](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/08/10/air-3-0-captive-runtime/).

Comment: Captive runtime is supported ONLY for Android and desktop apps. iOS apps still require a separate download.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ummm... incorrect.  iOS apps NEVER required a separate download.  Since Flex 4.5, the packager has used captive runtime by default.  You don't have a choice.  It is because iOS does not even allow third party runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

The AIR packager will give you the option of setting the download url (Amazon or Android Market for Android packaging, and the Apple store for iOS packaging) from where AIR will be downloaded.

Comment: This is outdated information.  Air 3.0 allows for "captive runtime"

Comment: Captive runtime is supported ONLY for Android and desktop apps. iOS apps still require a separate download.

Comment: Sorry, but this is plain wrong.  iOS doesn't even allow this for any platform.  "Captive Runtime" was invented for iOS and then brought forward for use in Android and Desktop.

Comment: See the document "Building ADOBE AIR Applications" that I cited in my answer where it says "On iOS, a separate AIR runtime is not installed; each iOS AIR app is a stand-alone application"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thanks, even though you're (hopefully) wrong, the discussion was of value. Upvoting.